# How to specify setting.php file for drush?

Tags: drush

I'm using Drupal 9 and Drush 11. I have two hosts, one for local testing (`www.en9-local.pglatz.com`) and a remote production server (`www.electronovelty.com`).

When I run drush status from either of these hosts, I see Site path is set to sites/default. How do I tell drush which settings.php to use? I tried using the uri argument on the command line; it does find the proper site path, but is also giving an error:

```
% drush status --uri=www.electronovelty.com
sh: 1: ^www.en9-local.pglatz.com$: not found
sh: 1: ^www.electronovelty.com$: not found
...
```

Ideally, it wouldn't involve editing files on the remote host, but set with a cmd line argument, env variable, or other setting outside the Drupal installation.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is this a multi-site? After you configured site aliases for Drush, you move into your local project dir and execute `drush cr` to clear your local site's cache and `drush @myalias cr` to clear your remote site's cache. If this is not a multi-site, settings.php always resides in sites/default dir. If this is a multi-site and you have another settings.php in sites/subsite dir for example, execute `drush cr -l subsite` to execute your local subsite's instance cache.

Comment: Maybe you are confused that Drush is not installed globally anymore? Drush nowadays only supports one install method: As a local dependency of a Composer-based site. However, you can easily write your own Shell alias to achieve what you want, receiving some argument to then take that and `cd` into the right local directory before executing a Drush command there, and maybe a second argument for the corresponding remote alias. And I think Drush still takes the `--root` option to point to a certain dir on your local, doesn't it?

Comment: That's `-l` then. `drush cr -l www.en9-local.pglatz.com` and `drush cr -l www.electronovelty.com`. (Although I'm not sure if this setup is a good idea in general.)

Comment: The problem I have is the site has a local and production version. I use the same codebase on both, and a settings file under sites for each, to point to the correct database (sites/www.en9-local.pglatz.com/settings.php, sites/www.electronovelty.com/settings.php). The sites run fine, but drush always uses sites/default/settings.php and I need a way to tell drush which settings file to use. Adding --uri to the drush command line results in the sh: errors above, as does using a site alias. I don't run drush on the remote site from my local, but do run it from the remote site itself.

Comment: Telling you this the third time now  ---> Use `-l`. Like `drush cr -l www.en9-local.pglatz.com`.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it, and as I mentioned, I see an error before the command (successfully) executes:
% drush cr -l www.en9-local.pglatz.com
sh: ^www.en9-local.pglatz.com$: command not found
 [success] Cache rebuild complete.

Comment: the command that should work for you is "drush @www.en9-local.pglatz.com cr" you need to take the name of the directory under the site folder

Comment: @HodbaKhalaf thanks but when I enter `drush @www.en9-local.pglatz.com cr` I'm getting `Command "@www.en9-local.pglatz.com" is not defined.` -- isn't this a site alias notation? Do I need to make an entry in self.site.yml to make this work? I tried, but get the same error,

Comment: I think it might be something wrong with the drush installation. Try. to go inside the site folder "cd sites/www.en9-local.pglatz.com" and run the drush command from there. If it didn't work then try to reinstall drush using composer